# What do "that" and "it" in "That's it" refer to?

Tags: pronouns

What do "that" and "it"in the following sentence refer to ?

> Schoolwork is almost everything, so we study hard and ***that***'s ***it***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say *"... and that's it"* is a shortened form of *"...and that's **all there is to** it."* The phrase is somewhat idiomatic.

*That* would refer to the notion that "schoolwork is almost everything." The sentence could be rephrased as, *"Schoolwork is almost everything, so we study hard and **there is nothing more to say about the matter**."* It's a way of expressing how we are resigned to the truth about something.

Comment: @J.R.I thought "that"refers to "our current situation" ,it refers to "the situation just mentioned we are in "

Comment: Generically speaking, yes. In the context of your sentence, "schoolwork is almost everything" is essentially "the current situation just mentioned." Obviously, in the sentence, _"I told you we are going to the dentist, and that's it,"_ the word "that" doesn't refer to "schoolwork is almost everything."